# .HTACCESS Dynamic URL Redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have this URL format:

```
<A href="/Conversations?Nicholas_Carter">Nicholas Carter</A>
```

How can I redirect if someone types: `/Conversations?` to: `/?Conversations`

My current codes are:
***for /Conversations?Nicholas_Carter***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Conversations.php?with=$1 [L,QSA]
```

***and for /?Conversations***

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ MainContents.php?page=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `/Conversations?` to: `/?Conversations` you can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*
RewriteRule ^Conversation/?$ / [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Can I also ask for **/Conversations?with=** to **/?Conversations**?